# How to run arbitrary rails code when binding.pry is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

Is there a way to run code just when `binding.pry` is called?  I want to do `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` to see sql queries.

I want this to run every time `binding.pry` is used, not just manually once.

Comment: You should get the pry "shell" and be able to run arbitrary Ruby. Are you having a specific issue?

Comment: clarified my question. I want it to run every time, and not have to re-enter every time

Comment: https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Hooks

Comment: @Stefan that looks like the answer. If you would like to make an actual answer with a brief description (for posterity), I'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pry hook can be executed just before landing on the pry prompt

```
Pry.hooks.add_hook(:before_session, "my_hook") do |output, binding, pry|
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
end
```

The pry folks have documented this well at github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Hooks